# Can't find the Show Changes function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't find the show changes function in excel, I've tried unhiding it, but it's still not showing! How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Excel did you use? Did you use the Protected Worksheet feature in Excel?

Comment: There has been a very concerted effort by Microsoft to move away from "tracked changes" and move to a "co-authored" document model.  If you are using an O365 version of Excel it's assumed you'll store the file online and co-author it, as opposed to the notion of sending the file around have having people make tracked changes.  If you still need the shared workbook functionality, search in the in-app help for how to enable the legacy "shared workbook" model.  Search for "Track Changes".

Answer (score 1):

you'll only get that in Excel Online for now. Soon it will be in desktop too. To see it save the excel file to OneDrive or sharepoint, and then open it in the browser.
Then you'll see 'Show Changes' in the Review Tab in the ribbon. [Show changes in ribbon_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr0WP.png)